# How can I alter LPCTSTR objects in C++?

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc

I have to alter some older C++ code and I'm not familiar with the language.

The code uses the MFC object CStdioFile and calls Open() to work with files.

`CStdioFile::Open()` takes an LPCTSTR argument to represent the filename and everything works fine when hardcoded like `_T("filename.txt")`.

But now I'm tasked to alter the code so that I can loop through files, or take the filename as a command line argument (However that works in a VC++ Project), which I know how to do fine with regular old CStrings and char arrays but then I'm getting many errors about not being able to convert char* or string into LPCTSTR.

I would like something that works like:

```
for( int i = 0; i < NUM_FILES; i++) {
  if (m_file.Open(_T("sample00" + std::to_string(i) + ".txt"), CFile::modeCreate | CFile::modeWrite | CFile::shareDenyNone | CFile::typeText, NULL))
  {
    // Do something
  {
}
```

The articles I've read about solutions to similar but not equivalent problems to mine are filled with warnings about inexperienced developers messing with strings in C++ (as a Python dev, I had no idea how good I had it).

Please advise.

Comment: That `_T` macro only works with string literals and is used to generate either `char` or `wchar_t` string literals depending on whether you are compiling against the "unicode" Win32 APIs or not.  First things first: Are you actually compiling against the Unicode Win32 APIs?

Comment: Does it answer your question to say the VC++ Solution with the hardcoded string and the  `_T` macro builds under both Release Win32 and Release Unicode Win32? And I have been working mostly with the non unicode builds, but I can switch to Unicode if there is helpful functionality.

Comment: OK, so you compile against both (which is unusual).  That means you are going to need to understand how to use `_T` macro compatible functions.  I will start you off with an answer that should answer your actual question.

Comment: I would use `std::string` and its `c_str()` member function. Like `m_file.Open(my_string.c_str(), ....)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LPCTSTR` is a typedef name for `const char *` or `const wchar *`, depending on whether you're using Unicode or MBCS/ASCII strings. The best way to do this in the modern style would be to build the string first, and then convert to the raw string using c_str().

```
for( int i = 0; i < NUM_FILES; i++) 
{
    std::string filename = "sample00" + std::to_string(i) + ".txt";
    if (m_file.Open(filename.c_str(), CFile::modeCreate | CFile::modeWrite | CFile::shareDenyNone | CFile::typeText, NULL))
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Or `std::wstring` and `std::to_wstring()` if `UNICODE` is defined.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use CString if you will continue with MFC

```
CString s;
s.Format(_T("sample%03d.txt"),i);
m_file.Open(s,....)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `_T` is a macro that basically allows the compiler to generate normal C string literals or wide character string literals depending on the value of the `_UNICODE` pre-processor macro.

I think this will do what you want for your first code example:

```
_TCHAR buffer[1024];
for( int i = 0; i < NUM_FILES; i++) {
    _stprintf(buffer, _T("sample%03d.txt"), i);
    if (m_file.Open(buffer, CFile::modeCreate | CFile::modeWrite | CFile::shareDenyNone | CFile::typeText, NULL))
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion:

```
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_FILES; i++)
{
    if (m_file.Open(CString(_T("sample00")) + CString(std::to_string(i).c_str()) + _T(".txt"), CFile::modeCreate | CFile::modeWrite | CFile::shareDenyNone | CFile::typeText, NULL))
    {
        // Do something
        {
        }
    }
}
```

You are confusing C++'s std::string objects with MFC's LPCTSTR and CString objects. You have to do some conversions when you are dialing with both. CStdio file accepts a LPCTSTR in its first parameter, and you can pass a CString to it, because the CString class implements the cast operator that will implicitly convert it to a LPCTSTR entity.

[image]